# common ActionBar component for all pages

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have angular2-nativescript application with several pages. structure is similar to [gloceries example](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/angular-end/app)
All pages has very similar action bar content so I don't want to add all action bar event handlers for each page or add custom component to each page template

Is there any way to have single ActionBar component for all application pages? Also it is important to have an ability to access this component from all pages and call its methods from page class (so I can tell this component that it should hide/show some content). I want to use some action bar animation in future so my ActionBar shouldn't be recreated each time page changes

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do it? I am now trying to have the same set of actionitems on everyp age + few ones I can add depending on context.

Comment: Yep, I've found the right way. I choose react-native :)